# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm getting an error in my logcat stating:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker
```

on the line `EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);`

Has anyone seen this before or know how to resolve it?

LOGCAT:

```
10-03 15:22:11.462: W/dalvikvm(10808): VFY: unable to resolve static method 100: Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;
10-03 15:22:11.942: I/System.out(10808): Sim State5
10-03 15:22:12.022: W/dalvikvm(10808): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad41f8)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at com.tf.st.stdatasettings.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:75)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4471)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
10-03 15:22:12.032: E/AndroidRuntime(10808):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SOURCE:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    private AnimationDrawable mGoButtonAnimation;
    Context c;
    boolean isAirPlaneMode;
    int simState;
    TelephonyManager tm;
    boolean NetworkConnection = false;
    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    //GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        simState = tm.getSimState();
        System.out.println("Sim State" + simState);
        Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_button);
        goButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.go_button_animation);
        mGoButtonAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) goButton.getBackground();


         EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a common dependency error, make sure that the Jar containing the class specified in the Exception is actually properly linked in your Java Build Path (Right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path). Also make sure that if you are using a Library Project the classes contained in it are being EXPORTED, in the Java Build Path screen go to Libraries / Order And Export and double check that they are properly configured and you are not missing that jar containing the class.

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: This helped me a lot.  In particular, making sure that the library is checked on the "Order and Export" tab.  I also find that for the new setting to apply, I need to clean the main project before relaunching.

Comment: how can I it in android studio ?